# how to convert multiple array to string in php

Tags: php

This is `var_dump` version:

```
array
  'content' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'complete' => boolean true
          'title' => string 'Season 1 Episode 11' 
      1 => 
        array
          'complete' => boolean true
          'title' => string 'Neutron: Boy Genius'
```

Comment: according to your array what string you expect ?

Comment: and also print_r(array) then var_dump .

Comment: you can use building function `implode()` you can check like `$result_string = implode(",", $my_array);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need like that:

```
Title: Season 1 Episode 11
Title: Neutron: Boy Genius
```

**Than try this:**

```
$array = array('content'=>array(
            array('complete'=>true,'title'=>'Season 1 Episode 11'),
            array('complete'=>true,'title'=>'Neutron: Boy Genius'),
        )
    );

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $valueInner) {
        echo "Title: ".$valueInner['title']."<br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i want to do is.you save my time.Thanks you so much!!!!

Comment: you are welcome, now mark as accepted the answer this will help for other who also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    $first = array(0=>array(1=>"Season 1 Episode 11",2=>"Neutron: Boy Genius"));      foreach($first as $x => $x_value) {foreach($x_value as $r=>$resultarr){
$result = $resultarr." ";
echo $result;}}?>
```

Comment: this is response from REST so i want to remove this    array
  'content' => how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. your array will be converted into string. :-

```
print_r($array, 1);
```